# How can I tell if my suggestions have become a form of bullying

Tags: discipline, maturity, bullying

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What constitutes verbal abuse of one's child?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/what-constitutes-verbal-abuse-of-ones-child)

I am worried that my constant reminders and punishments are being taken as bullying. 
I might be over reacting but then again, I might not.

I imagine a youth reacts to bullying differently when its from an elder. Is there any research or experience on this matter? The last thing I want to do is mentally abuse a child.

Comment: What's the age of the child? That would have a big influence on the answers. Older kids are expected to be able to think for themselves, and they know the consequences of their (in)actions beforehand.

Comment: Apart from the accepted answer, [this answer](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/1413/109) may be particularly helpful to you?

Comment: That is also useful. Thanks @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion (and I work in a school) bullying is the 'go to' word today.  Any thing and Every thing is considered bullying.  Disciplining your child and correcting the behavior is not bullying.  How to discipline appropriately is probably a separate question.